# "AND" and "OR" query together using range easticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have searched a lot but I got nothing for my case.

I have posts in elastic search. I want to get posts that

- author_id = 2 OR post_id = 2
- AND created > 1524722310000

I used this but did not work. It retrieves all posts that **created** > 1524722310000 and does not check **author_id** and **post_id** !

```
query: {
  bool: {
    should: [
        {match: {"author_id" : 2}},
        {match: {"post_id"   : 2}}
    ],
    filter: [
        {range: {"created": {gte : startTime , lte:targetTime}}},
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you're only missing one thing, i.e. to specify that at least one `should` clause should match and you can do it like this:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    minimum_should_match: 1,               <-- add this line
    should: [
        {match: {"author_id" : 2}},
        {match: {"post_id"   : 2}}
    ],
    filter: [
        {range: {"created": {gte : startTime , lte:targetTime}}},
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: anything else needed here?

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this, 

query: {
    bool: {
        must: [
                {match: {"author_id" : 2}},
                {match: {"post_id"   : 2}},
                {range: {"created": {gte : startTime , lte:targetTime}}}
              ] 
          }
      }
```

Comment: This will require that **both** `author_id` AND `post_id` match, while the OP would like an OR instead.